# Adding editable infoboxes to Google Maps API v3 DrawingManager markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I just came across the fantastic [DrawingManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing) class for Google Maps API v3 -- which is exactly [what I need](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69281/are-there-any-good-libraries-for-visually-creating-simple-google-maps/70741) for my "create a map" webapp.

Alas, adding a marker tool only drops the marker itself onto the map -- I need the ability to add infoboxes to markers, preferably similar to how [Google Maps Engine](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/?pli=1) does it (I.e., you place a marker and can click on it to set title and description).

Is there something I'm missing (Possibly a property I need to set to get this type of behaviour), or will I need to wire together my own implementation? If the latter, know of any helper classes that might make this easier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first link you posted, at the bottom of that page there is section "Drawing Events" which begins to explain that the DrawingManager would have an event 'markercomplete' which returns the actual marker instance. See also DrawingManager api docs (see events and their arguments) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DrawingManager

So, once you have access to the instance of the marker which was just created, it's just a matter of creating InfoWindow's and handling things from there.

```
//code
```

Here is an example fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/A96Hu/

Comment: Hey, any idea how I'd access the InfoWindows after I've created them? Thanks!

Comment: If you mean you'd like to get the data of each markers info window content as well as other things like it's actual position, here is an advancement with a few other tweaks too (added allowing dragging of marker for fine tuning while settingsInfoWindow is open, among other improvements). Note the markers are now stored in array, and use of a getMarkersData() function http://jsfiddle.net/A96Hu/3/

Comment: That's a great update. One point to note for anyone arriving from Google -- the info window has to close before the marker is "saved" to the marker array. It might be worthwhile programmatically closing all infowindows before the report is generated via the "generate report" button.